# Event listener when changing HTML on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this problem, I need to be able to catch when html change inside a html element.

I have this button that is updating his html with `data-*` when I scroll down the page it shows `Load More` when triggered with scroll it shows a gif `<img id="img-loading" src="assets/img/loading-2.gif" width="170" height="113">` and then shows again `Load More`until there are items.

I would be able to catch when the gif is visible, then his parent `div` shouldn't have css borders.

```
<div class="tg-ajax-button tg-nav-color tg-nav-border tg-nav-font" data-item-tt="119" data-button="Load More" data-loading="<img id=&quot;img-loading&quot; src=&quot;assets/img/loading-2.gif&quot; width=&quot;170&quot; height=&quot;113&quot;>" data-no-more="No more item" data-remain="" style="color: rgb(228, 229, 230);">
<span class="tg-nav-color sp-btn-gray" style="color: rgb(228, 229, 230);">Load More</span>
</div>
```

I've tried with jQuery `change()` on html with:

```
$('.tg-ajax-button .tg-nav-color').html().change(function() {
  alert('changed');
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

---

My Solution:

I was using a Wordpress plugin "The Grid" that use an AJAX request to load elements in the grid. To add a gif instead of the text, I used jQuery `html()` to change html inside the button with `.ajaxSend()`

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
    if ($('test').hasClass('img-loading')){
      $('test').html('<img id="img-loading" class="img-loading" src="http://www.h-57.com/test/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/assets/img/loading-2.gif" width="170" height="113">');
      $('test').parent('span').attr('style',  'border-color: transparent !important');
    }
});
```

Now everything is working fine, but I think it's pretty messy, so if someone has better ideas, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Do you update the html with AJAX ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel Yes, I'm using a Wordpress plugin to manage grids and it is updating grids with AJAX but I don't want to hardcode the plugin.

Comment: With ajax, you could know when the request succeeds (in your case when your htlml is updated).

Comment: @SébastienGicquel ok but how I can check that AJAX request and not another?

Comment: I am not sure why you can't just put the code in the events for changing the load more link with image and vice versa but if you want to catch html changes, you can use MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @SamuilPetrov maybe with the link it's more clear... http://www.h-57.com/test/work/?lang=en when it is loading more items the buttons becomes a gif but it has borders and I need to remove that borders only when the gif is shown

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click event to a  element. When the user clicks on the button, output "Hello World" in a

element with id="demo":
use the code as accordance to your need

```html
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

hope this helps :D

Comment: thanks Nabiulla but I don't have to change HTML. I need to catch when html is changing.

Answer (score 0):

it seems u want a function like: page scroll to bottom, then load more data.

it can separate to 2 parts:

1. when page scroll to bottom, then start a ajax
2. before ajax, change "LOAD MORE" to "LOADING IMG", after ajax, change it back

the code looks like:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
     if( scrollToBottom ) {
         loadData();
     }
})

function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
      ...
      beforeSend: function(){ 
         // change 'LOAD MORE' to 'LOADING IMG'
      },
      complete: function() {
        // change 'LOADING IMG' to 'LOAD MORE'
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hello 喝茶的螃蟹, thanks for your help. I already have a function like this. I don't know how to clear explain my problem, maybe a link can helps http://www.h-57.com/test/work/?lang=en when you scroll down the page, the 'Load More' button becomes a gif with loading animation. I would like to remove from that button css borders only when the gif is shown

Comment: it seems the btn css defined in class 'sp-btn-gray', u can remove this class when change 'LOAD MORE' to gif, and add this class when change gif to 'LOAD MORE'.

Comment: I'm doing like this but the problem is that the AJAX request is made by the-grid.min.js that is a plugin and I don't want to hard code it.

Comment: in that case, u should read the plugin's document for help. what's the fullname of the plugin?

Comment: Thanks, I've already read the documentation but no info about this. This is why I'm asking here how to catch changes in html or as Sebastian suggest in a comment above with `.ajaxComplete()`. Now I'm able to remove borders but no way to restore classes after load is complete because of some delays in the plugin animation.